# Python class declare by passing variables

Tags: python, class, attributes, getattr, dremio

I try to create an object by passing the variables, but it seems not work.

I put a simple example below to show what I want. Please help me to deal with this issue.

Successfully

```
temp = catalog.TEST
temp = catalog.PROD
```

Not works, it pass string "i" instead of the list element as attributes

```
lists = ['TEST,'PROD']
for i in lists:
    temp = catalog.i
```

Complete code
I'm using dremio-client this package (https://dremio-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)

```
import dremio_client as dc
mydremio = dc.init(os.getcwd() + '/.config')
catalog = mydremio.data
# TEST and PROD are the folders that exist in my dremio server
a = catalog.TEST
b = catalog.PROD
# Cannot pass the list element to object "catalog" 
list = ["TEST","PROD"]
for i in list
   temp = catalog.i
```

Thanks Pavel for the solution, but I have a one more complicated question.

```
list = ["TEST","TEST.DEMO"]

# what's work - directly declare
test = catalog.TEST.DEMO

# works for "TEST" not works for TEST.DEMO
for i in list:
    temp = getattr(catalog, i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `temp = catalog.i`, you actually trying to set an attribute `i` of the `catalog`, not value under variable `i`.

You can try using `getattr` instead:

```
import dremio_client as dc
mydremio = dc.init(os.getcwd() + '/.config')
catalog = mydremio.data
# TEST and PROD are the folders that exist in my dremio server
a = catalog.TEST
```

For the second case you can try to do something like this:

```
for i in list:
    fields = i.split('.')
    temp = catalog
    for field in fields:
        temp = getattr(temp, field)
```

What I do here is split `i` by `.` symbol to create a list of fields that I need to access.
So `"TEST.DEMO".split('.')` will become `["TEST", "DEMO"]`
Not sure if it will work, but I just wanted to show the main idea.

Comment: Thanks Pavel it works, but I got additional questions.
I just update my questions.